# Create path in ADLS Gen2 fails because of missing x-ms-blob-type?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-rest-api, azure-sas

I created an Azure Storage Account with an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2. I want to upload a file using the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/storageservices/data-lake-storage-gen2). While using the authorization with [Shared Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key) works fine, I get problems using an [account SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview).

For the path creation I use the [Path - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/create) operation.

```sh
# provide Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 URL as environment variable
$ ADLS_URL="https://xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/files"

# provide account SAS as environment variable
$ SAS="sv=2017-07-29&ss=bf&..."

# Create a new path in ADLS Gen2
$ curl -vX PUT -H "Content-Length: 112" "$ADLS_URL/example.txt?resource=file&$SAS"
```

The request returns with `400 An HTTP header that's mandatory for this request is not specified.` and the following error message.

```xml
<Error>
  <Code>MissingRequiredHeader</Code>
  <Message>An HTTP header that's mandatory for this request is not specified. RequestId:870e754b-... Time:2020-07-07T...</Message>
  <HeaderName>x-ms-blob-type</HeaderName>
</Error>
```

It turned out, that the missing header is required for the [Creation of a blob in the Blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob). Since the ADLS Gen2 supports both APIs and both provide a similar operation, it delegates the request to the wrong one.

Is there a way to create a path using PUT operation with a SAS on the ADLS Gen2 API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a path(a file in this example) using PUT operation with a SAS on the ADLS Gen2 API. But you need take 3 steps: **create an empty file** / **append data to the empty file** / **flush data**.

**Step 1:** after generating a sas token, you need to call the [Path - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/create) to create a file in ADLS Gen2. **Note:** the file should be empty here, it means that in the request header, `Content-Length` should be `0`.

The request url looks like this:

https://xxx.dfs.core.windows.net/aaa/myfile999.txt?resource=file&sv=2019-10-10&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupx&se=2020-07-08T10:31:37Z&st=2020-07-08T02:31:37Z&spr=https&sig=xxxx

Here, I tested it with the tool [postman](https://www.postman.com/), it works without issue. The empty file can be created on ADLS Gen2 in azure portal:

[image]

**Step 2 and Step 3:**

then you should call [Path - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/update) for **appending data**.

at last, call the [Path - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/update) again for **flushing data**.

If you don't know how to use [Path - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/update) for these operation, please use fiddler to see the detailed request information, or just let me know:). Here is the screenshot of the request captured by Fiddler:

[image]

**BTW,** I suggest you can directly use the [Put Blob api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob) with **sas token**(but you need to specify `x-ms-blob-type` in the request header), which is just a one step for both create the file as well as upload content.

Comment: It turns out, that I used another URL with `blob.core.windows.net`. Switching to `dfs.core.windows.net` raises an error, `400 - UnsupportedRestVersion`. Did I miss something?

Comment: @sschmeck, which version of the rest api you're using(you can use fiddler to figure it out)?

Comment: and as I mentioned in the answer, if it's not necessary to use the ADLS Gen2 api, you can choose to use blob api which is more easier:).

Comment: Thx @Ivan. I used a SAS gererated by Terraform with `sv=2017-07-29`. Generating a new one manually produces `sv=2019-10-10`. It fixes the issue with with the `UnsupportedRestVersion`.